# Must declare the scalar variable "@user_code" in parameterized query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parameterized

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim param As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@user_code", SqlDbType.Char, 4)
    param.Value = "0016"
    Const sqlstr As String = "select sectors.sector_code,sector_name   from user_sectors inner join sectors on user_sectors.sector_code = sectors.sector_code  where user_code = @user_code  and sectors.sector_code not in ('z')"

    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr, _con)
    da.Fill(ds)
    ddl.DataValueField = "sector_code"
    ddl.DataTextField = "sector_name"
    ddl.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    ddl.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: check the aded code help you to resolve your issue

Comment: Essesntially, you declare an `SqlParameter` but you don't do anything with it. Your need to add it to an `SqlCommand`. Or just use EF or some other ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for adding parameter  to dataadapter

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data 
             Source=localhost;Database=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetProducts", conn);
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  command.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
  SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  adapter.Fill(ds, "Products");
```

**add parameter to you data adapter object like this**

```
da.Parameters.Add(param)
```

this is missing in your code

MSDN : [**Using Parameters with a DataAdapter**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: cannot resolve symbol Parameter. my problem still not solved.

Comment: @AdityaPratapSingh - check the msdn link where you can find example how to add parameter to the dataadapter....